# extract_images dropping frames

Tags: ros, image-view, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All

I have noticed that when I used the extract_images in image_view pkg to extract images from a bag file, it drops frames.

Even if I set the "sec_per_frame" close to zero like 0.0000000000001 or modify the code that do not consider delay in line :
if(delay >= sec_per_frame_)

still the number of frames which is extracted is less than the actual recorded frames ?

I noticed this by extracting the header information directly from a bag file and find the number of frames in bag file is greater than number of frames from extract_images.

I appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28006/extract_images-dropping-frames/) by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on 2012-06-13**:
This is worth reporting as a bug (if you haven't already):
http://www.ros.org/wiki/Tickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just to update. I ended up writing my own code based on the current extract_images. I remove the delay part and I saved all the images to the disk. The problem is with the way the delay is set and if the frame rate is too high it keeps dropping frames!

---

Originally posted by [Eddit](https://answers.ros.org/users/1712/eddit/) with karma: 94 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1